# How to send WebRTC audio from Kurento to Avaya phones

Tags: sip, rtp, kurento, avaya, mu-law

I am successfully using Kurento's `RtpEndpoint` type to connect to several Asterisk SIP servers as well as directly to several models of SIP phone, but connections to Avaya SIP servers do not work, and I am trying to figure out why. The symptom is that the connection is made but there is no media.

For the RTP Endpoint, Kurento generates the following SDP (which I munge to include the public IP address and remove the video portion) which I then include in the SIP `INVITE`:

```
v=0
o=- 3807878922 3807878922 IN IP4 192.0.2.95
s=Kurento Media Server
c=IN IP4 192.0.2.95
t=0 0
m=audio 18848 RTP/AVPF 96 0 97
a=setup:actpass
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=rtpmap:96 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000
a=rtcp:18849
a=sendrecv
a=mid:audio0
a=ssrc:2835743000 cname:user3268188862@host-ad591d54
```

A working connection with an Asterisk server returns the following SDP back to Kurento:

```
v=0
o=root 55778749 55778749 IN IP4 198.51.100.252
s=Asterisk PBX 13.28.1
c=IN IP4 198.51.100.252
t=0 0
m=audio 11704 RTP/AVPF 0
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=maxptime:150
a=sendrecv
```

In the Kurento log, I see that it says it is transcoding this connection.

A non-working connection with an Avaya server returns the following SDP back to Kurento:

```
v=0
o=- 1598890119 2 IN IP4 203.0.113.100
s=-
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:64
t=0 0
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 96 0 97
a=inactive
a=rtpmap:96 opus/48000/2
a=rtpmap:97 AMR/8000
a=ptime:20
```

As you can see, the Avaya server responds that it cannot use any of the available codecs and therefore will not send or receive media (`a=inactive`).

According to some Avaya documentation I found, Avaya SBCE supports transcoding at least the following codecs:

- OPUS 12kbps narrowband
- OPUS 16kbps narrowband
- OPUS 18kbps wideband
- G.722
- G.711ulaw
- G.711alaw
- G.726
- G.729AB

Kurento supports using PCMU (a.k.a. G.711ulaw) as shown in the working Asterisk sample, but Avaya seems to reject it. (Note: I previously thought that it wasn't included in the SDP, but it is there as the `0` in the `m=audio` line.) I tried to get it to force using PCMU using `rtpEndpoint.setAudioFormat(AudioCaps(AudioCodec.PCMU, 8000))`, but that didn't help.

My second thought was to change the OPUS bitrate using `rtpEndpoint.setAudioFormat(AudioCaps(AudioCodec.OPUS, 18000))`. When I tried this, not only did it not work with the Avaya phones, but it also stopped working with Asterisk since Asterisk was using PCMU. I thought of munging the SDP to change it to `opus/18000`, but that's not allowed, as [RFC 7587](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7587#section-7) explicitly states:

> The media subtype ("opus") goes in SDP "a=rtpmap" as the encoding
> name.  The RTP clock rate in "a=rtpmap" MUST be 48000, and the
> number of channels MUST be 2.

How can I get Kurento and the Avaya SBCE to send media between themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the only way I could get it to work was to put a Kamailio/RTPEngine server in between them and allow it to negotiate separately with both sides.